# Is it possible to restore a SQL Server database in Azure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a backup of a SQL Server 2008 database.  I'd like to restore it as an Azure SQL Server database.  Is this possible?

P.S.  I've seen a couple of questions to this effect from 2014.  Is it possible today?

Comment: Though not from a backup but I have created an Azure SQL Database from a SQL 2008 database using SSMS 2016. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, no it's not possible.

The Unsupported in SQL Azure doco https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-transact-sql-information/  directs you to BOL and `RESTORE` shows it's not available in SQL Azure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to restore the backup to an instance of SQL 2008 on-premises/locally first?  If so you can then use management studio to Export the data and schema as a BACPAC or DACPAC file (export data tier application), which can then be imported into an Azure database using the Import data tier application.  You can also use the Taks -> Generate Scripts option from the database node in the management studio, ensure you check on include schema and data - then the SQL files can be executed against your SQL Azure instance as well.

There are some features which aren't available in SQL Azure that are on the server product, but the import will tell you about those if there are any - things like FILESTREAM aren't supported in Azure.  Here is the link to take you through steps to [migrate from SQL server to SQL Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/) - and [here are the differences](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-transact-sql-information/) in supported features between the two.

I have some production databases in Azure and frequently download them as data tier apps, import them into a local instance of SQL Server to do some debugging or testing, its a painless process.